# How to obtain node package seach paths for an arbitrary file in an arbitrary directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, typescript-compiler-api

Suppose two files in different directories `x.ts` and 'y.ts`Within the code file`x.ts` I can write this code to output the node search paths in order:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(require.resolve.paths(''),null,2))
```

and it gives some output like

```
[
  "/mnt/common/github/tscapi/tmp/node_modules",
  "/mnt/common/github/tscapi/node_modules",
  "/mnt/common/github/node_modules",
  "/mnt/common/node_modules",
  "/mnt/node_modules",
  "/node_modules",
  "/home/craig/.node_modules",
  "/home/craig/.node_libraries",
  "/home/craig/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node"
]
```

What I would like to be able to do is get the corresponding paths for `y.ts`, but generate them from the code in `x.ts`.

I could find nothing in the requirejs package that allows this, I couldn't find any packages available for doing this, and I couldn't find any related questions.

One strategy would be to write it "by hand" based on node specs, and/or to appropriately mangle the paths from `x.ts` to be correct for `y.ts`.  Possibly error prone.

Another strategy would be to copy `x.ts` content to a file in the directory of `y.ts`, execute it, and capture the output.  But that is really brutal.

Best would be to find an existing solution.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `createRequire` to get a require function for the module in question.

Since this is tagged with typescript-compiler-api, you can also ask TS to resolve a module path, which will give you many more paths since it is also checking for TS specific file extensions.

```
const { resolve } = require("path");
const { createRequire } = require("module");
const ts = require("typescript");

const yPath = resolve("./path/to/y.js");
const testRequire = createRequire(yPath);

console.log(testRequire.resolve.paths(""));

const resolved = ts.resolveModuleName("", yPath, {}, ts.sys);
console.log(resolved.failedLookupLocations);
```